# DATEPART function assigning

Tags: sql, sql-server, inner-join, getdate, datepart

[image]

I have table who order a order today and yesterday (18,17)

I need to find those result .

```
select A.C_Name 
from Customer_Table A
 inner join
 Order_Table O
   On A.C_ID=O.C_ID
   where DATEPART(DAY,Order_Date)=GetDATE() and
  DATEPART(DAY,Order_Date)=GETDATE()-1
```

I didnt get result for above query .

Comment: WHY ARE WE SCREAMING?!

Comment: sorry . what does mean

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_caps#Association_with_shouting.5B10.5D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want orders today and yesterday, then this should be sufficient:

```
where Order_Date >= dateadd(day, -1, cast(getdate() as date))
```

(This assumes no future order dates, which seems reasonable).

Your query is a mess for several reasons.  `datepart()` returns an integer and you are comparing it to a date.  Looking at just the "day" part of a date will not work on the first of the month.  And, `getdate()` -- despite its name -- has a time component, so direct equality is inappropriate.

Comment: Thank you @Gordon Linoff

Comment: @sampathacharya if this answer solved your problem, you have to accept it, to learn more about accepting and upvoting answer read the [Tour page](http://www.stackoverflow.com/tour)